# Uploading file with parameters using RxAlamofire

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rxalamofire

I have an array of images.

```
let images:[UIImage]
```

I want to upload images to the server, after uploading each image I will get the URL of the image as a response.

How to organize a uploading chain(loop) and get all responses using RxAlamofire?

P.S. I did not find examples of uploading multipart data to the server using RxAlamofire

Comment: There is an example of uploading multipart/form-data in [Alamofire's main repository](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-multipart-form-data), maybe you can deduce a way of doing it in RxAlamofire with it.